# How to code services in wordpress?

Tags: android, web-services, wordpress

See am doing an android application,it has a web back end,am using wordpress as the web back end,but how can i code web services in wordpress?suppose i need to fetch some contents from database and pass it as json to android phones.So where should i place the php script or how can i do this?Is it possible to do web services using wordpress?

Here is the code:

```
$select_qry="select * from admin_details where username='$uname' and  password='$paswd'";
$result=mysql_query($select_qry);
$rows=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($rows>0)
$admin_arr=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
json_encode($admin_arr);
```

How can i do this in wordpress?

Please help me..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these steps:

1. Create a template with your PHP code
2. Create a page.  Let's say the admin page is /my-service. Assign the template you created in step 1 to this page.

Your adroid application can now call your wordpress service via the URL .  mydomain.com/my-service.

Notes:

1. I assumed you meant a REST service.
2. Creating web services in WP is possible, but not ideal because URL pathing would be very hard. i.e. Wordpress wouldn't know how to parse  /player/id  vs /player/id/status   .. the first asks for all the player data, the second asks for a particular attribute of a player.